# \href crossing a page boundary messes up link in second column

Tags: xetex, hyperref, paracol

I'm using `\href` (from the [hyperref package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) to put some links into a document which is being typeset in two languages using the [paracol package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) and `XeTeX`.

To compile it, I'm using

```
texify -p --engine=xetex paramin.tex
```

If in column one, I have a link that crosses a page boundary, the first paragraph containing a link after a `\switchcolumn` command gets linked to the target of the `\href` that crosses the page boundary.

Here's an example (as minimal as I could make it):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
I see a strange phenomenon regarding the behaviour of \verb+\href+ and page breaks when using the \textit{paracol} package. This document is designed to show the behaviour. This paragraph contains a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{link} to some website, this one works as expected.
\switchcolumn
This paragraph contains a link at the end that should actually point to the same website as the one in the left column, but it gets messed up by the link in column one which crosses a page boundary. Updating the MiKTeX packaged didn't help. \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{link}.
\switchcolumn
Here's a few empty lines to save me writing more text. As an example, I include a link to \href{http://www.brockhaus.de/}{my favourite search engine}.

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

~

Now we're all set I think. The link contained in this paragraph \href{http://www.error.com/}{is slightly longer than normal and crosses a page boundary}. This will result in it being repeated in the wrong place in column two on page one.
\switchcolumn
This again points to \href{http://www.brockhaus.de/}{my favourite search engine}. As only the first link in a column gets messed up, this one behaves as it should.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

And here's an elaborately illustrated screenshot of the resulting document:

[image: screenshot of the resulting document]

Any idea how to fix this? I have some control over the content, so I may be able to avoid a page break within a link.

Adding or removing just one empty line in this example fixes the resulting document, so I'm pretty sure the page break within the link in combination with paracol is the culprit.

Comment: As it stands your minimal example compiles with an error under the `minimal` document class. Switching to the `article` document class doesn't produce an error, but the layout has changed. Are you using the `minimal` document class for a particular reason/purpose? See [Why should the `minimal` class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/5764)

Comment: @Werner Sorry, I've made two schoolboy errors. One, I probably tried to over-simplify the minimal example by using `minimal`. Two, I failed to mention that I compile this using the `--engine=xetex` switch. I changed the document class to `article` now. This also fails using `pdfLaTeX`, but 'succeeds' with XeTeX and produces the invalid pdf shown. Thanks for the hint re. `minimal`, I wasn't aware of that.